# How To expose assets(icons/images) url path in CSS file while creating a custom library in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular8, assets

Hi I've created a custom library in angular. When I'm consuming it in My application It works fine in local environment But when I deploy the application in production environment the base-href of the application changes. So in deployed environment my application is not able to resolve assets path used by library as the request url for assets call doesn't append extra url added due to build so it is returning 404. I've tried by giving assets(icon/images/fonts) path both relative and absolute in scss file.

Can Someone please help How to expose assets path in scss file while creating custom library in Angular ?

I tried below options but that couldn't solve the probem:

.

```
icon-settings {
    background-image: url('/assets/icons/Settings.svg');
}
.icon-settings {
    background-image: url('assets/icons/Settings.svg');
}
.icon-settings {
    background-image: url('../assets/icons/Settings.svg');
}
```

Comment: please check in your angular.json file if you are exporting the assets folder correctly.
For example, 
"assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              },
...

Comment: yes I'm doing that already like   {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/till assets path of library",
                "output": "./assets"
              }

Comment: my application is able to copy all the library assets but issue is the path which I've given in scss file of library is not able to appened my application's base-href in it's css path

Comment: Were you able to come up with a clean solution?